# COUNT and GROUP BY performance

Tags: mysql

I have a table where I store visits (id, datetime, country, browser). I want to count how many visits are from which country.

I use this query:

```
SELECT country, COUNT(*) as hits 
FROM hits_table 
WHERE timestamp >= CURDATE()
GROUP BY country
```

But the dataset is huge. So if I add `LIMIT 10` to only get the top 10 countries will it improve the performance?

```
SELECT country, COUNT(*) as hits 
FROM hits_table 
WHERE timestamp >= CURDATE()
GROUP BY country LIMIT 10
```

Also I don't need exact results I only need some approximate results. So can't I make the query so it skips every 2nd result. Will it improve the performance? Are there any other methods?

Comment: Do you want the top 10 countries, ordered by what? If it is by the most hits, then you need to use `ORDER BY hits DESC LIMIT 10` and it won't be more efficient than the whole result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**: No.

**Detailed answer**: Unless you add/already have an index there that covers the `country` column the database engine has no way of telling the total number of instances to count. Even if you limit the output the entire table has to be scanned to retrieve every instance first. Of course, since this is a logging table, with potentially a large dataset, I'd avoid adding indexes to the table so:

- not to increase `INSERT` time
- to minimize space/memory usage the indexes would otherwise require

**Solution**: create a second table that will keep a running total for all countries, that gets updated by a trigger on the `hits_table` or directly by the application that inserts the data into `hits_table`. Something in the lines of:

```
CREATE TABLE `country_hits_totals` (
  `country` VARCHAR(255),
  `date`    DATE,
  `visits_total` BIGINT
);
```

This would make the table very small and allow you to create a `PRIMARY KEY` on the `country` and `date` columns, dedicating minimum resources. Once that key is set up, you could employ a trivial *upsert* statement (see [this SQL Fiddle session](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1467c/1/0) for a full test case with a trigger-based usage):

```
INSERT INTO `country_hits_totals` (
  `country`,
  `date`,
  `visits_total`
)
SELECT
  NEW.country,
  NEW.timestamp,
  1
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `visits_total` = `visits_total` + 1;
```

**Query blocking note**: In a heavy traffic scenario you ideally want to query `country_hits_totals` with non-blocking statements only. Otherwise the *upsert* on the trigger gets delayed, and by extensions entire transaction that kicked it off. In a perfect world `country_hits_totals` would get copied over to a data warehouse at the time of least daily traffic, and you'd run your BI queries on that warehouse. That said, this is large traffic/enterprise territory and possible solutions depend on how quickly you want to get the data. Say, if you need an update only once a day you're better off pre-aggregating data onto `country_hits_totals` on a schedule instead of relying on a trigger updating the rows live.

Comment: I guess you know that MySQL triggers are row-based so they might be more of a problem in a write-intensive load (I mean more than keeping an index updated.)

Comment: @ypercube absolutely, hence `FOR EACH ROW` trigger syntax :-). That said, we're facing a logging table here so rows are written out one-by-one anyway. Given this and the "Query blocking note" paragraph I don't see any immediate problems (correct me if I'm wrong, though). In a perfect world the application would be putting any low-priority logging information onto an EMS queue that would get written out to a database or a warehouse at a time of least traffic precisely to avoid unnecessary database contention.